# how to iterate over dictionary in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm doing the apple playground tutorial and came across this section:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime": [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13],
    "Fibonacci": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8],
    "Square": [1, 4, 9, 16, 25],
]
var largest = 0
var largestKind = String()
for (kind, numbers) in interestingNumbers {
    println(kind)
    for number in numbers {
        if number > largest {
            largest = number
            largestKind = kind
        }
    }
}
largest
largestKind
```

The problem is that it is not finding and printing the largest kind. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If I copy/paste that in to a new playground, it outputs `25` and `Square` for me...

Comment: In playground it prints `25` and `Square` - that seems the expected output. What do you have instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted works perfectly for me. I assume that you are viewing the output in playgrounds. However, playgrounds isn't always perfect. Try print(largestKind) or try adding some random code after that or open a new playground.